# How to generate WCF proxy for .NET 4.0 from assembly in .NET 4.5 using svcutil?

Tags: .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I have written a server side application (system service) running WCF service host and client application, both in .net 4.5, using duplex net.tcp connection. Everything works fine (generating proxy on client side from server assembly using svcutil).

Now I get a request to transform client side application to .NET 4.0, to be able to run on Windows Embedded (XP based).

The problem is, I am not able to generate client proxy without async methods using `svcutil` for .NET 4.5, nor to generate proxy using `svcutil` for .NET 4.0, because server assembly is written in .NET 4.5.

Is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: _"I am not able to [...] generate proxy using svcutil for .NET 4.0, because server assembly is written in .NET 4.5"_ - what does the tool tell you when you try?

Comment: Error is: Cannot load file C:\ServerApplication.exe as an Assembly. Check the FusionLogs for more Information. But I have found the solution now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. Because generating client proxy is two step process (generating metadata and generating client from metadata), I split these steps and used for each step different svcutil:

- used svcutil from .NET 4.5 to generate metadata
- used svcutil from .NET 4.0 to generate proxy from metadata

-

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\svcutil" "..\ServerApplication\ServerApplication\bin\Debug\ServerApplication.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\svcutil" *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C# /out:ClientApplication\ServerApplicationClient.cs /noConfig
```